# square root system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> I have a system of equations as follows that I need to solve for $x$:
>   $$
> \sqrt{1 - x^2} + \sqrt{4 - x^2} = z\\
> \sqrt{4 - y^2} + \sqrt{9 - y^2} = z
> $$

Originally, I was trying to put $x$ in terms of $z,$ but I’m at a loss how I would solve this system. Trying to solve it just makes it more complicated, no matter if I multiply by the reciprocal or square both sides.

Comment: Are you looking for real or integer or complex solutions?

Comment: I am looking for real/integer solutions.

Comment: You ask to solve for $z$, but the system is already solved for $z$ in terms of both $x$ and $y$ -- so what are you asking for exactly?

Comment: If you want integer solutions, it's clear that all four surds must give integer results; there aren't many possiblities.

Comment: I guess I’m looking for x or y. I edited the question.

Comment: It does not have to be integer, but it’s definitely not complex

Comment: Saw the words “root system.” Definitely not what I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, we can choose to deal only with positive $x,y,z$ values. Notice that $y\le2$ from the first radical in the second equation. Then $y$ varies between $0$ and $2$, so $z$ varies between $\sqrt 5$ and $5$. Similarly, in the first equation $x\in[0,1]$ so $z\in [\sqrt 3,3]$. Combining the two ranges for $z$ means a possible solution can be found if $z\in [\sqrt 5,3]$.

Let's focus now on the first equation, and do the substitution $u^2=1-x^2$, with $u\ge 0$. In fact $u\in [0,1]$. We can then rewite the first equation as $$u+\sqrt{3+u}=z$$
Leaving just the square root on the left, and squaring the equation, you get $$3+u=(z-u)^2$$
This is a simple quadratic in $u$, which you should be able to solve. Choose the solution that is in the $[0,1]$ interval.

Comment: Wouldn’t of thought of that, thanks

Comment: What is $u$ representing

Comment: Nothing. I just wanted a different name for the variable. My first idea was $\alpha$, but then I decided that it's too much typing

Answer (score 0):

Both the $x$ and $y$ equations have the form
$$\sqrt{a^2-h^2} + \sqrt{b^2 - h^2} = c$$
For everything to be real, we need $\sqrt{|a^2-b^2|} \le c \le a + b$.

Assume this is satisfied. For positive solution of $h$, this equation has a geometric interpretation. It is the equation for the height $h$ of a triangle of side $a,b,c$ with respect to side $c$. We can use
[Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula) to figure out the area $\Delta$ of the triangle and then

$$\begin{align}h = \frac{2\Delta}{c}  
&= \frac{1}{2c}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)}\\
&= \frac{1}{2c}\sqrt{4a^2b^2 - (c^2-a^2-b^2)^2}\end{align}$$

Apply this to the equations at hand. For positive $x$ and $y$ solutions, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{1 - x^2} + \sqrt{4-x^2} = z &\implies
x = \frac{1}{2z}\sqrt{16 - (z^2-5)^2}\\
\sqrt{4 - y^2} + \sqrt{9-y^2} = z &\implies
y = \frac{1}{2z}\sqrt{144 - (z^2 - 13)^2}
\end{align}$$